# Track internal users frequented pages for future

Tags: c#, asp.net, settings, html

I am redesigning our intranet site and one of the items I want to include is a personal quick jump to the top 3 most frequented pages that each user goes to on a regular basis.

I am not sure on how to track the most frequented pages and I am not sure how it should be stored, either personal settings or database.

Comment: You need to log each page view on the database / per user, keep the counter and then show it... too much statistic data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a database. If you are using a master page, you can store a key/value pair in the database of the page and the counter of how many times they visited that page. On Page_Load of the Master Page, if the Page isn't PostBack, insert/update the counter in the database. This would be the simplest way to do it. I would provide a code example, but this is very complex and it would be overkill.

Comment: How about the profile properties within the web.config? That would work as well right.